# RxJS Angular How to access data dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two components and a service. HomeComponent is the parent component and ContactComponent is the child component that has an array with two elements for two contacts.

However I have one observable that I want to use and I want to store the returned data from ContactComponent and have them in two variables in Home Component.

Here is my code:

Service

```
export class AppDataService {

  constructor() { }

  private data = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Home");

  //this is what your components subsribes to
  currentData() : Observable<string> {
     return this.data.asObservable();
  }

  //this function allows you to change the value to be accessed by other components
  changeData(message: string) {
    this.data.next(message);
  }
}
```

ContactComponent.ts

```
public contactsChanged = new Subject();
  public updatedContact:any;
  constructor(private contacts: Contacts, private storage: Storage, private appData : AppDataService) {
    this.getContact();
  }
  key = 'contacts';
 mContacts = [
   {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   }
  ];



  pickContact(contactId) {


    this.appData.currentData().subscribe((message:string) => this.updatedContact = message);   


    this.mContacts[contactId].name = "Mitchell";
    this.mContacts[contactId].number = (Math.random() * 0.5).toString();

    this.appData.changeData(this.mContacts[0].number);
    this.appData.changeData(this.mContacts[1].number);

     console.log("contactsChanged: " + this.mContacts[0].number);
     console.log("contactsChanged: " + this.mContacts[1].number);
 }
```

HomeComponent.ts

```
this.appData.currentData().subscribe((message:string) => {
      //here i log changes detected on the console
      console.log("i have changed " + message);     

      //you can perform any call or action here e.g
      //update a variable
      this.numberOne = message;
      this.numberTwo = message;
      //or call a function
      this.canCall();
  });
```

I want to store the first element's number in numberOne and the second number in NumberTwo. However obviously this stores the same number.

Comment: If you want to send *pairs* of values around, change it to `Observable<[string, string]>`.

Comment: could you please be more specific

Comment: Well currently you have everything built around `Observable<string>`, which sends a single value at a time. Now you're saying you want to deal with *pairs* of values. So send a [*tuple*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), `Observable<[string, string]>`, then you get both values at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class AppDataService {

  constructor() { }

  private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]); // or null, type any can be changed with a interface that follow ur contact object

  //this is what your components subsribes to
  currentData() : Observable<[string, string]> {
     return this.data.asObservable();
  }

  //this function allows you to change the value to be accessed by other components
  changeData(contact: [string, string]) {
    this.data.next(contact);
  }
}
```

```
public contactsChanged = new Subject();
  public updatedContact:any;
  constructor(private contacts: Contacts, private storage: Storage, private appData : AppDataService) {
    this.getContact();
  }
  key = 'contacts';
 mContacts = [
   {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   }
  ];



  pickContact(contactId) {


    this.appData.currentData().subscribe((message:[string, string]) => this.updatedContact = message);   


    this.mContacts[contactId].name = "Mitchell";
    this.mContacts[contactId].number = (Math.random() * 0.5).toString();

    this.appData.changeData([this.mContacts[0].number, this.mContacts[1].number]);

 }
```

```
this.appData.currentData().subscribe((contacts:[string, string]) => {
      //here i log changes detected on the console
      console.log("i have changed " + contacts);     

      //you can perform any call or action here e.g
      //update a variable
      this.numberOne = contacts[0];
      this.numberTwo = contacts[1];
  });
```

You also can save the array of objects if you want to save directly all the data of your contacts.

Comment: Why make it *`any`*?

Comment: that can be string[] or contactsInterface[]

Comment: Or even more explicitly a tuple, as I already mentioned above, which also provides length information. If you're going to use TypeScript, *use* TypeScript.

Comment: the question not put info related if that array will the same all time so you can't use a tuple. if that array is static you are right.

Comment: The question's clearly hard-coded to deal with 2, if that number *can* vary the OP's made their own life very difficult...

Comment: The array must be static, and I intended it to be that way. Anthony your answer is correct but I shall also post what I have as it also works.

Comment: So sorry for miss understood, edited for tuple type.

Answer (score -1):

App data Service

```
export class AppDataService {

  constructor() { }

  private data = new BehaviorSubject<[string,string]>(['Home','Home']);

  //this is what your components subsribes to
  currentData() : Observable<[string,string]> {
     return this.data.asObservable();
  }

  //this function allows you to change the value to be accessed by other components
  changeData(numberOne: string,numberTwo:string) {
    this.data.next([numberOne,numberTwo]);
  }
}
```

ContactComponent.ts

```
public contactsChanged = new Subject();
  public updatedContact = ['',''];

  constructor(private contacts: Contacts, private storage: Storage, private appData : AppDataService) {
    this.getContact();
  }
  key = 'contacts';
 mContacts = [
   {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    number: ''
   },
   {
    id: 1,
    name : '',
    number: ''
   }
  ];



  pickContact(contactId) {

    this.appData.currentData().subscribe(([numberOne,numberTwo]) => 
    [this.updatedContact[0] = numberOne,this.updatedContact[1]=numberTwo]);             

    this.mContacts[contactId].name = "Mitchell";
    this.mContacts[contactId].number = (Math.random() * 0.5).toString();

   this.appData.changeData(this.mContacts[0].number,this.mContacts[1].number);

     console.log("contactsChanged: " + this.mContacts[1].number);


  }
```

HomeComponent.ts

```
this.appData.currentData().subscribe(([numberOne,numberTwo]) => {
      //here i log changes detected on the console
      console.log("HomeComponent NumberOne " + numberOne, "numberTwo" + numberTwo);     

      //you can perform any call or action here e.g
      //update a variable
      this.numberOne = numberOne;
      this.numberTwo = numberTwo;
      //or call a function
      this.canCall();
  });
```